# Attacked in Markarth, Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I enter Markarth Keep and get to the first set of stairs towards the King all the guards become hostile and start attacking me. Nothing happens until I reach this point, not even if I drag my weapon. As soon as I reach the stairs they attack me, with or without my weapon drawn.
I only have an 5 gold bounty, and I haven't threatened anybody.
What's wrong? Have anybody else experienced this?

Comment: Have you recently been working on the Forsworn Conspiracy quest by chance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I secretly kill every guard in a town?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39361/can-i-secretly-kill-every-guard-in-a-town) The question name doesn't make it sound like a duplicate but if you read the answer you'll see why it's a dupe.

Comment: @Katustrawfic having the same answer does not mean that it's the same question.

Comment: This was a recent quesetion... Brotherhood quests can affect this so can your level of Vampirism (more specifically, level 4).

Answer (score 2):

Try committing a minor crime in the city(not the keep) so a guard approaches you in the usual manner. Pay off your bounty or go to jail either way your bounty should reset to zero, preventing this from occurring.

Comment: Worth noting that if you opt to do go to jail, you should remove any stolen items from your inventory, otherwise they'll be confiscated and you'll lose them.

Comment: @Alex Before the game decides to reset a chest I'd put my stolen stuff in "Evidence" anyday. The hardest part about getting it back is figuring out where the jail is.

Comment: "Had your stolen stuff stolen? Steal it back!" :) If I recall chests in your home never get reset, but with Skyrim's bugs anything is possible...